# 'setenv' command not working on tcsh shell when called explicitly

Tags: linux, shell, python, tcsh

I can run setenv command just fine in my tcsh shell like this:

```
echo $0
/usr/bin/tcsh
echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/tcsh
setenv START_TIME `date +%s`
echo $START_TIME
1499355967
```

But, whenever I run it explicitly like shown below, it doesn't work. I need to do this because I have to specify shell when executing it via python subprocess call, otherwise it will call a `sh` shell as default.

```
/usr/bin/tcsh -i -f -c 'setenv START_TIME `date +%s`'
echo $START_TIME
START_TIME: Undefined variable.
```

What's the problem here? I searched for this issue online, but couldn't find any issue similar to this. This is extremely frustrating.

Comment: A child process (such as your `tcsh -c ...`) cannot alter the environment of the parent process. If you need to change the environment of a particular process, do it in that particular process.

Comment: @thrig, thanks! That was the issue, I'll try using set instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a separate invocation of the shell when you use `/usr/bin/tcsh` on the first line of your script. The `echo` command runs in the 'enclosing' shell - the one that has the commands in it.

Why not run *both* commands on the first line, like this:

```
/usr/bin/tcsh -i -f -c 'setenv START_TIME `date +%s`; echo $START_TIME'
```

Then they are both running in the same invocation of the shell. Replace the `echo` command with a call to your python program if you wish.